# Mendeley - add notes to research

Tags: research-process, academic-life, literature-search, reference-managers

I am using mendeley to save papers etc. which have come up during my research. However, I am often having some ideas about problems which are interesting or some links which are worth reading later. I would like to add this to mendeley easily, sth like a workable document.

Is sth like that possible? What are you using for a problem like that?

I appreciate your answer!

**Update**

I am looking for a way to add general notes, which are not paper related?

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mendeley does let you add notes to your papers: On the right where the bibliography data is normally displayed there is a tab label notes.

Additionally you can add annotations when to a document you open in Mendeley using the buttons at the top.

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, how to add general notes, which are not paper related?

Comment: @Kare You'll need a different program for that. Evernote is quite good although I prefer simple Notepad(++).

Comment: Note that the notes field has a maximum length, which isn't clearly signalled. I just lost a half a day's work to this by writing notes on my phone that apparently got too long for the online database: when I synced, the last notes were just gone. gg 

Answer (score 3):

Mendeley is a great tool, but my personal preference while taking general notes is [Evernote](https://evernote.com/). The best feature being that it'll sync automatically to all your devices.

Mendeley is something that I use when I have to compile from a huge collection of papers.